# Why can't I run any of my JavaScript in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Can't remove JavaScript errors or run any of my own JavaScript on my page. Getting "function undefined" errors. Console showing Javascript errors coming from trendtext.eu. Is this malware?

Comment: What does this have to do with malware? You haven't even asked a question

Comment: canonical questions need to attempt to be more coherent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely the Chrome extension "Responsive Web Design Tester" crashing javascript on your web pages. Extension must've been compromised and appears to be removed from the Chrome Extension web store now. To remove it, open Chrome and select the top left menu option "Chrome". Click "Preferences" and select "Extensions". Scroll down to "Responsive Web Design Tester" and uncheck the "Enable" option. Feel free to delete the plugin as well, as it appears to be unsupported at this time.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this worked.  I just disabled the `Responsive Web Design Tester` extension as I will need it in the future.  At that point, I'll enable it and disable it when I'm done.  Thanks!

Comment: True. spread the word. Too bad, because this extension was good.

Answer (score 4):

Responsive Web Design Tester silently loads javascript activity tracking library from trendtext.eu website which collects information about what you do, what pages you visit and how knows what else.

It is the same spyware script that was reported here http://news.softpedia.com/news/download-manager-s3-firefox-add-on-spies-on-users-495228.shtml

Comment: It is the case with trendtext.eu, the Responsive Web Design Tester has been compromised.